# Cannot load php extensions

Tags: php, mysqli, openssl

Usually I have no problem setting up a web server under apache but here I encounter an error and I find no solution. Attached is the phpinfo ()

[image]

I encounter the error

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0`

same for `openssl` and `pdo_mysql` But the extensions are well installed and activated

`untitle@untitle:~$ ls /usr/lib/php/20190902/`

`calendar.so  exif.so      ftp.so      iconv.so  mbstring.so  opcache.so    phar.so      shmop.so    sysvsem.so ctype.so     ffi.so       gettext.so  intl.so   mysqli.so    pdo_mysql.so  posix.so     sockets.so  sysvshm.so curl.so      fileinfo.so  gmp.so      json.so   mysqlnd.so   pdo.so        readline.so  sysvmsg.so  tokenizer.so`

For openssl

[image]

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.1.1g
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
Openssl default config => /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

My /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini

```
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

/etc/php/7.3/mods-available

```
untitle@untitle:/etc/php/7.3/mods-available$ ls
calendar.ini  gettext.ini   mysqlnd.ini    posix.ini     sysvsem.ini
ctype.ini     iconv.ini     opcache.ini    readline.ini  sysvshm.ini
exif.ini      json.ini      pdo.ini        shmop.ini     tokenizer.ini
fileinfo.ini  mbstring.ini  pdo_mysql.ini  sockets.ini
ftp.ini       mysqli.ini    phar.ini       sysvmsg.ini
```

The full error with composer :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/openssl.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/openssl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gmp' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for dompdf/dompdf v0.8.5 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.5].
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.8.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.2].
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[1.0.3].
    - phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[7.0.10].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.2].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.3].
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v6.11.0 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ^2.2.1 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.2].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v6.11.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.11.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

thanks in advance

**EDIT : its done !**

**It's ok, I completely reinstall apache2 and php7.4, I also delete php7.3 which is causing the problem. problem solved**

Comment: It doesn't look like it loaded (in my case) 20-mysqli.ini in the additional ini files.  Have you installed the extension - `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`?

Comment: `Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
php-mysql est déjà la version la plus récente (2:7.4+76).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 2 non mis à jour.`

In english, yes its installed

Comment: Can check if you have some form of mysql.ini, or just add `extension=mysqli.so` to your php.ini file (listed in the phpinfo output).

Comment: thank for your reply, i just update my post. But same error

Comment: I notice that your entries do not have the .so on the end.  Also mods-available does not mean enabled.

Comment: No change, im sorry. The error comes in installing the composer dependencies. I will put the error in full

Comment: I'm trying to completely uninstall apache and php to see